# How to require npm 'which-country' with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on my first Node & Angular project and have tried to require the node package 'which-country'. However I don't understand how to use this inside an Angular controller and keep getting an error message. I have looked online and have tried to solve the problem using browserify and am having the same problem. A lot of tutorials seem to ask me to use grunt/gulp but I'd prefer not to if possible (I'm already taking on a lot of news things and would prefer to keep it simpler.

Inside my index.html file I have included all the js files that I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/controllers/main.js"></script>
```

Do I have to export the bundle.js file and then require it in the Angular controller? I have tried doing that but keep getting a `ReferenceError: require is not defined` error message, although I'm pretty sure that my syntax is probably wrong when trying to require it

Here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var wc = require('which-country');
```

And my main.js (where all my Angular code lives):

```
(function() { 

    var travelApp = angular.module('travelApp', []);
    travelApp.controller('TravelAppController', function($scope, TravelAppFactory) {
        $scope.currencyConverter = function(origin, destination) {
            // irrelevant code her
            var originLat = origin.geometry.location.lat();
            var originLng = origin.geometry.location.lng();
            var originCty = wc([originLat, originLng]);
        };
    });
}());
```

Comment: browsers currently don't support CommonJs modules natively. are you using any modules library? show us the code inside main.js controller

Comment: Browserify is indeed the right way to include `npm` CommonJS modules on the Browser. Please provide information about how you have tried this and we can help you out.

Comment: @Maximus & @DustinToothless Sorry for forgetting that, I have edited the question to include it. The error comes on the line where I use `wc([originLat, originLng])`, I thought that as I used `var wc = require('which-country');` and then use a script tag for the bundle.js file that would work?

Comment: @jSutcliffe90, I assume this `var wc = require('which-country');` happens on the server side, but your angular app is running on the client side. You need to send whatever the `wc` is exporting to the cient side

Comment: @Maximus Would you mind showing me how? So I have added `var wcExport = function() {
    var wc = require('which-country');
};

module.exports = wcExport;` to the server.js file and then `var wcExport = require('/server.js');` inside the controller but am still getting the same require error message. I'm sure this is just a syntax thing at this point but I don't understand how exporting modules works after looking at tutorials

Comment: @jSutcliffe90, as I said, you can't require modules inside angular without using additional libraries like webpack or browserify. If you need to use `which-country`, it seems that you can go into its folder inside `node_modules` and run `npm run generate`. this will generate `data.json`, which you then can reference inside `<script src="node_modules/which-country/data.json">` tag